# How to change an iOS app icon in Crashlytics / Fabric

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I've updated the app icon resource but I can't find a way to reflect this on Crashlytics / Fabric.

Answer (score 17):

Mike from Fabric here.

It should be picked up on the next build and run of your app. That's when check to determine if there is an updated app icon.

**Updated Answer:**

We now provide a way for you to upload the icon manually.  To update your app’s icon, log into your account, [head to your app’s settings](https://fabric.io/settings/apps) and click on the current icon. Select your new icon and upload it to change the icon in Fabric. The icon will not change again until a new manual upload happens.

Comment: hi mike, it's not woking. i tried restarting fabric client app, restarting xcode, creating another target with the same bundle id but nothing worked. do you know if i can delete the app from crashlytics and register it again in a safe way?

Comment: It's  not pulling up within the Fabric dashboard at all? Try bumping the build and version number and see if that helps.

Comment: Same issue here, no matter what I do the app icon doesn't update on Crashlytics :(

Comment: @PauloFierro Can you email into support(at)fabric(dot)io with your bundle id and info.plist?

Comment: I am also facing same issue, so far any solution ? @MikeBonnell , Please suggest something. Xcode 8, Fabric 2.5.2.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Thanks for your reply.  I cleared the cache, uninstall the fabric, installed again, login again, somehow It was still appearing same icon. But once I build and released my app, it started work smooth with the original (expected) app icon. :)

Comment: @MikeBonnell - please look at my answer, this is the only way how I did it.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Does the manual way mean the automatic way does no longer work?

Comment: The automatic way works when an app is added for the first time. After that, you need update to the icon manually.

Answer (score 1):

Well, unfortunately, Mike's answer did not help me, but I've found a way to do it.

- go to the web page `fabric.io`
- log in into your account
- on the top right corner - select the gear (settings) icon
- select `apps` (most left option)
- find your app for which you want to update icon on `Fabric`
- select app
- you will see app icon in the center of screen
- click on it - and it will open the window asking you to select image from your computer (in my case Mac)
- upload required image asset
- profit :)

Comment: Yep, that's a newer way to do it that was only added recently!

Answer (score 1):

Click setting, and choose your app, then you can change your app icon by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In my case changing `Version number`, `Build number` and app reupload helped. Of course I needed to do it few times and occasionally logout from Fabric app. So it's really random.